# Issues with changing state of each item in a list in React Todo-App

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling

I'm building my own sort of To-do app in React, but putting my own twist on it and making it about building a baking recipe. Currently, I'm trying to build a function that "halves/doubles" the recipe. I use UseState to initially set the ingredients, and when the button to halve the recipe is clicked, it calls handleHalve which updates the state of the ingredients by mapping over each ingredient and changing its quantity to 1/2 of it. The function sort of seems to be doing what I want it to do (I achieve it by making each ingredient an object with ingredient text and quantity properties), but my app completely glitches when it happens (It'll halve the ingredients but then they'll all glitch and disappear). Here's my code for handleHalve:

```js
const handleHalve = () => {
    const newIngredients = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
      const newQuantStr = (ingredients[i].quant / 2).toFixed(1);

      console.log(newQuantStr);

      const newQuant = parseFloat(newQuantStr);

      console.log(newQuant);

      const plural_adjusted =
        newQuant === 1 ? ingredients[i].units : ingredients[i].units + "s";

      const units_adjusted =
        ingredients[i].units === "n/a" || ingredients[i].units === "unit-type"
          ? " "
          : plural_adjusted + " of ";

      const newText =
        newQuantStr + " " + units_adjusted + ingredients[i].ingredient;

      const newIngredient = {
        ...ingredients[i],
        quant: newQuant,
        text: newText,
      };

      newIngredients.push(newIngredient);
    }

    setIngredients(newIngredients);
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Any debugging I try to use with console.log() within the handleHalve function also disappears, so I'm having trouble figuring out what the issue is. I'm super new to React (I'm doing this project to learn), so please bear with me if it's something small.

EDITS: Apparently my function does work fine. Here's the rest of my code for context:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AddIngredient from "./AddIngredient";
import { Ingredient } from "./Ingredient";
import EditIngredient from "./EditIngredient";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

export default function IngredientsList() {
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);

  const addItem = (ingredientText, ingredient, quantity, units) => {
    const new_id = uuid();
    const newIngredients = [
      {
        text: ingredientText,
        ingredient: ingredient,
        id: new_id,
        edit: false,
        quant: quantity,
        unit: units,
      },
      ...ingredients,
    ];
    setIngredients(newIngredients);
  };

  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    setIngredients(ingredients.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  const editItem = (id) => {
    setIngredients(
      ingredients.map((item) =>
        item.id === id ? { ...item, edit: !item.edit } : item
      )
    );
  };

  const editText = (ingredeintText, ingredient, quantity, units, id) => {
    setIngredients(
      ingredients.map((item) =>
        item.id === id
          ? {
              ...item,
              ingredient: ingredient,
              quant: quantity,
              unit: units,
              text: ingredeintText,
              edit: false,
            }
          : item
      )
    );
  };

  const handleHalve = () => {
    const newIngredients = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
      const newQuantStr = (ingredients[i].quant / 2).toFixed(1);

      console.log(newQuantStr);

      const newQuant = parseFloat(newQuantStr);

      console.log(newQuant);

      const plural_adjusted =
        newQuant === 1 ? ingredients[i].units : ingredients[i].units + "s";

      const units_adjusted =
        ingredients[i].units === "n/a" || ingredients[i].units === "unit-type"
          ? " "
          : plural_adjusted + " of ";

      const newText =
        newQuantStr + " " + units_adjusted + ingredients[i].ingredient;

      const newIngredient = {
        ...ingredients[i],
        quant: newQuant,
        text: newText,
      };

      newIngredients.push(newIngredient);
    }

    setIngredients(newIngredients);
  };

  const handleDouble = () => {
    const newIngredients = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
      const newQuantStr = (ingredients[i].quant * 2).toFixed(1);

      console.log(newQuantStr);

      const newQuant = parseFloat(newQuantStr);

      console.log(newQuant);

      const plural_adjusted =
        newQuant === 1 ? ingredients[i].units : ingredients[i].units + "s";

      const units_adjusted =
        ingredients[i].units === "n/a" || ingredients[i].units === "unit-type"
          ? " "
          : plural_adjusted + " of ";

      const newText =
        newQuantStr + " " + units_adjusted + ingredients[i].ingredient;

      const newIngredient = {
        ...ingredients[i],
        quant: newQuant,
        text: newText,
      };

      newIngredients.push(newIngredient);
    }

    setIngredients(newIngredients);
  };

  return (
    <div className="recipe-app">
      <h1 className="my-recipe">My Recipe</h1>
      <div className="magic-buttons">
        <form onSubmit={handleHalve}>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="halve-btn btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm"
          >
            {" "}
            Halve my Recipe!{" "}
          </button>
        </form>
        <form onSubmit={handleDouble}>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="double-btn btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm"
          >
            {" "}
            Double my Recipe!{" "}
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="list">
        <AddIngredient addItem={addItem} />
        {ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
          if (ingredient.edit) {
            return <EditIngredient id={ingredient.id} editText={editText} />;
          } else {
            return (
              <Ingredient
                ingredient={ingredient}
                deleteItem={deleteItem}
                editItem={editItem}
              />
            );
          }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The function itself [works fine](https://9rnh9l.csb.app/). Please provide the rest of your code or some reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks so much for looking over it. I've posted the rest of my code

Comment: Also, if it helps, before everything disappears when I click the halve/double buttons, it names the ingredient "undefined."

Comment: The problem is that you're calling the function on submitting the form, which by default reloads the page. You need to either call `e.preventDefault()` in your handler to prevent reloading, or just have a button with an onClick event outside of any form, as it's not really needed here.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! This makes total sense and completely worked. Also the undefined section was totally my own typo (I accidentally spelled one of the properties wrong when accessing it).